# TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined in React js

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

an getting an error while while submit the form , error are mentioned below..

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined

if you want any more information tell me

> reducer/index.js

```
export default (posts =[], action) => {
   switch(action.type){
       case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts. action.payload];
       default:
            return posts;
   
   }

}
```

> Actions/posts.js

import * as api from '../api';

//action creators

```
export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ALL', payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }

}

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) =>{
    try{
        const {data} = await api.createPost(post);
        dispatch({type: 'CREATE', payload:data})
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

> API/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = "http://localhost:7000/posts";

export const fetchPosts = () =>  axios.get(url);

export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url,newPost);
```

Comment: Need more information on which the line of occurence of error and more stack trace if possible

Comment: I think you should put a comma after the posts in CREATE `case 'CREATE':
            return [...posts. action.payload]`

Comment: what does the data from getposts and createposts console.log as? before it is dispatched?

Comment: @FotisTsakiris Interesting, usually most compilers throw a different error for these types of runtime issues

Answer (score 0):

You declared data  wrong way.

```
export default (posts =[], action) => {
      switch(action.type){
   case 'FETCH_ALL':
        return action.payload;
    case 'CREATE':
        return [...posts. action.payload];
   default:
        return posts;
```

}

}

You remove . by ,

```
  case 'CREATE':
        return [...posts, action.payload];
```